# Colour the background of a ggplot polygon to match the lower value of the contour layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, contour, shapefile

I have produced a map using a kernel density estimation which I have previously generated using the 'bkde2d' function from the kernsmooth package. I'm using ggplot to plot the density surface under my shapefile like so. Test = my data frame containing coordinate values (IDLon and IDLat) along with the kernel density estimation (KDEst). ScotMap.df is my shapefile data frame.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_contour(data=test, aes(x=IDLon, y=rev(IDLat), z=KDEst)) +
  stat_contour(data=test, geom="polygon", aes(x=IDLon, y=rev(IDLat), z=KDEst, fill=..level..)) +
  geom_polygon(data=ScotMap.df, aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group, col="lightgrey"), fill="lightgrey") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = b[1,]) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = b[2,]) +
  theme_bw()
```

which produces this plot:

[image]

What I would like to do is match the lower end of the density surface colour from '..level..' to the rest of the plot so everything that currently appears white is dark blue. This would make the density surface look continuous across the whole image and effectively assign a 0 value at a particular coordinate to the same colour as the lower end values. I tried fudging it by matching the colours manually but nothing on the colour pallette is identical so the best I could do was this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_contour(data=test, aes(x=IDLon, y=rev(IDLat), z=KDEst)) +
  stat_contour(data=test, geom="polygon", aes(x=IDLon, y=rev(IDLat), z=KDEst, fill=..level..)) +
  geom_polygon(data=ScotMap.df, aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group, col="lightgrey"), fill="lightgrey") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = b[1,]) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = b[2,]) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "blue4"))
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the documentation for `scale_fill_gradient`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html) the lowest value of the scale is `low = "#132B43"`, while the highest is `high = "#56B1F7"`.

```
data_frame(x = sample(1:5, 5), y = sample(1:5, 5), z = rnorm(5)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile(width = 1, height = 1, colour = "white") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#132B43"))
```

[image]

Also, drop the `col = "lightgrey"` that's inside the `geom_polygon(aes(...))`, or move it outside the `aes(...)` to get rid of your extra legend entry (which is also why it's coming up as the wrong colour).

## Edit:

```
require(scales)
data_frame(x = sample(1:5, 5), y = sample(1:5, 5), z = rnorm(5)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile(width = 1, height = 1, colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "seq", palette = "YlGnBu") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = brewer_pal(type = "seq", palette = "YlGnBu")(6)[6]))
```

[image]

```
   require(viridis)
    data_frame(x = sample(1:5, 5), y = sample(1:5, 5), z = rnorm(5)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile(width = 1, height = 1, colour = "white") + 
      scale_fill_viridis() +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = viridis_pal()(6)[1]))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks @Brian. Is there a way to change the base colour of "..level.." to change the surface it to a blue-yellow pallette (or something else)? Also, do you know of a way to remove the contour lines and be left with a continuous surface?

Comment: You can use `+scale_fill_gradient()` to set any high or low values you like. A good option is `scale_fill_viridis()` from the `viridis` package, which has four palette options. For blue-yellow in particular, I'll edit my answer.